# JPA, removing an object from an Hashset of an entity requires a getter to be called for the persistence to work

Tags: java, jpa, entity, persistence, getter

I'm trying to **persit** the changes I make to an **entity** when I try to **remove an object from an Hashset**. I don't understand why my **first two versions doesn't work** while **the third one does.**

In the fifth test, I update the entity

In the sixth test, I try to check that the update from the previous test is still effective. Three versions of the "remove" methods produces different results for this test. The first two doesn't work while the third one does.

Tests setup

```
  @Inject
  private InvitationManagerBean invitationManagerBean;
  private Student host1;
  private Attendant guest;
  private int id;
  private Attendant guest2;
  private Attendant guest3;
  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  @Deployment
  public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
      .addPackage(InvitationManagerBean.class.getPackage())
      .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
      .addAsManifestResource(new ClassLoaderAsset("META-INF/persistence.xml"), "persistence.xml");
  }

  @Before
  public void initialize() {
    host1 = new Student("john", "wick", "johnwick@gmail.com");
    guest = new Attendant("tony", "iommi");
    guest2 = new Attendant("marge", "simpson");
    guest3 = new Attendant("homer", "simpson");
  }
```

Fifth test, **this test works with every version of the remove method**

```
@Test
@InSequence(5)
  public void removeTest() throws StudentDoesNotExistException, GuestDoesNotExistException {
    //query
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Student> criteria = builder.createQuery(Student.class);
    Root<Student> root = criteria.from(Student.class);
    criteria.select(root).where(builder.equal(root.get("mail"), host1.getMail()));
    TypedQuery<Student> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteria);
    Student res;
    res = query.getSingleResult();

    assertEquals(3, res.getGuests().size());
    assertTrue(res.hasInvited(guest));
    assertTrue(res.hasInvited(guest2));
    assertTrue(res.hasInvited(guest3));
    assertTrue(invitationManagerBean.remove(res, "homer", "simpson"));
    assertEquals(2, res.getGuests().size());
    assertTrue(res.hasInvited(guest));
    assertTrue(res.hasInvited(guest2));
    assertFalse(res.hasInvited(guest3));
  }
```

Sixth test that **fails with the first two version of the "remove" method**.
The assertEquals fails because **the value is 3 instead of 2**, which means that **the remove operation from the fifth test does not works**

```
  @Test
  @InSequence(6)
  public void removeNotExistTest() throws StudentDoesNotExistException, GuestDoesNotExistException {

    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Student> criteria = builder.createQuery(Student.class);
    Root<Student> root = criteria.from(Student.class);
    criteria.select(root).where(builder.equal(root.get("mail"), host1.getMail()));
    TypedQuery<Student> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteria);
    Student res;
    res = query.getSingleResult();
    assertEquals(2, res.getGuests().size());           //IS 3 WHEN FAILS
  }
```

The **first version of the remove method**, and **the first removeGuest() method on which it relies**.

```
public boolean remove(Student host, String name, String lastName) throws StudentDoesNotExistException, GuestDoesNotExistException{
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Student> criteria = builder.createQuery(Student.class);
    Root<Student> root = criteria.from(Student.class);
    criteria.select(root).where(builder.equal(root.get("mail"), host.getMail()));
    TypedQuery<Student> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteria);
    Student s;
    Attendant guest;
    guest = new Attendant(name, lastName);

    try {
      s = query.getSingleResult();


    } catch (NoResultException e) {
      throw new StudentDoesNotExistException("the host does no exist");
    } catch(Exception e){
      return false;
    }

    if(!s.hasInvited(guest)) {
      throw new GuestDoesNotExistException("tried to remove a guest that has not been invited");
    }
    s.removeGuest(guest);                 //CHANGE IS HERE


    return true;
```

```
  public void removeGuest(Attendant a) {
    guests.remove(a);
  }
```

The **second version of the remove method** relies on a **second version of the removeGuest method** in the Student class:

```
  public void removeGuest(Attendant a) {
    getGuests().remove(a);
  }
```

The **third version** of the remove method...

```
s.getGuests().removeIf(v -> v.getName().equals(name) && v.getLastName().equals(lastName));
```

... relies on the following removeGuest() method:

```
  public void removeGuest(Attendant a) {
    guests.remove(a);
  }
```

The class Student

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "S")
public class Student extends Attendant implements Serializable {


  @Pattern(regexp = "\\d{10}+", message = "Invalid creditCardNumber")
  private String creditCard;

  @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Set<Attendant> guests;

  public Set<Attendant> getGuests() {
    return guests;
  }

  public Student() {
    super();

  }

  public Student(String name, String lastName, String mail) {
    super(name, lastName);
    this.mail = mail;
    guests = new HashSet<>();
  }

  public String getCreditCard() {
    return creditCard;
  }

  public void setCreditCard(String creditCard) {
    this.creditCard = creditCard;
  }


  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
    Student student = (Student) o;
    return Objects.equals(mail, student.mail) && Objects.equals(creditCard, student.creditCard);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(super.hashCode(), creditCard, mail);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Student{" +
      "creditCard='" + creditCard + '\'' +
      "} " + super.toString();
  }

  public void addGuest(Attendant a) {
    guests.add(a);

  }

  public void removeGuest(Attendant a) {
    guests.remove(a);
  }

  public boolean hasInvited(Attendant a) {
    return guests.contains(a);
  }

}
```

Attendant equals and hashcode

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Attendant attendant = (Attendant) o;
        return name.equals(attendant.name) &&
                lastName.equals(attendant.lastName) ;
    }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name, lastName);
  }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with JPA. What does the javadoc of [Set.remove()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) say? How does it find the object to remove inside the set? What do you conclude?

Comment: It uses the equals method, but I have overriden it in the Attendant class. And the update works in the fifth test with every version of the method

Comment: So, put a breakpoint in your equals methods, and see why they return false. My guess is that homer simpson is a Student, and not an Attendant.

Comment: Also, your hashCode() method is incompatible with equals(): it uses the credit car in hashCode, and the credit card isn't used in equals(). Two equal objects MUST have the same hashCode.

Comment: Sorry my explainations weren't accurate, I've just edited

Comment: That doesn't make your hashCode implementation more correct. And it doesn't tell us if homer simpson is an attendant, or a student, or something else.

Comment: I've just edited and run the update, I have the same results. Homer  Simpson is an Attendant for sure

Comment: That still doesn't tell us if homer simpson is an attendant, or a student, or something else. Your Attendant hashCode method could also be wrong: you haven't posted it.

Comment: I have added it